# No. of pathways from one point to another in a square grid

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 by 4 square grid pathways connecting southwest end and northeast end. How many different ways do exist?

My Anwser: $8C4$ I took it that there are 8 right's, RRRRRRRR. However, we need 4 of these R's to be Ups or U's, which implies we need $8C4$ such combinations. Does this make sense?

Comment: That first sentence is deeply unclear.

Comment: You should edit the question to include two things: (1) the motivation and background of the question, and (2) your rationale for the answer. As in all advanced mathematics, the numerical value of the answer is of less interest than the rationale behind it.

Comment: Supposing you cannot come back, you can either go Right (R) or Up (U). The discription of each of the possible paths wil be a "word" made up of the letters R and U (for example RRRRUUUU). How many such words are there?

Comment: @BernardMasse Its the same logic as I've used in my answer, so its the final result $8C4$ ?

Comment: The statement of your question is unclear.  Do you mean that there is a grid formed by $5$ horizontal line segments and $5$ vertical line segments (forming $16$ squares)?  Is there an implicit assumption that the person travels from the southwest corner to the northeast corner only by traveling north or east along the gridlines?  If so, please edit your question accordingly.  Without this information, it is difficult to confirm that you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

***YEAH THAT'S RIGHT.

In a 4x4 grid, to end go southwest to northeast end, we have 8 choices of which 4 are right and the other up; then the total number of minimum paths (→ ↑) is 8C4.***